# Golang set http response code based on struct field

Tags: http, struct, go

Within an api I'm writing I have an error struct which marshals to json. When the api has an error it returns the struct and I set the http response code to be the appropriate value.

```
type PodsError struct {
    ErrorCode       int     `json:"error_code"`
    CallingFunction string  `json:"calling_function"`
    Message         string  `json:"error_message"`
}

type PodsErrorWrapper struct {
    Error   PodsError   `json:"error"`
}
```

Right now every time I write the struct I also write a header, but I don't like the amount of duplicate code I am seeing.

```
error := PodsError{http.StatusNotFound, "Calling Func", "Message"}
response.WriteHeader(error.ErrorCode)
response.WriteEntity(PodsErrorWrapper{error})
```

Is it possible to move the WriteHeader call to something that gets called whenever I pass the error to WriteEntity()? I figure there has to be a function I could implement for a PodsErrorWapper where I could just set the http status to be whatever the ErrorCode field is.

Edit: Sorry I forgot to mention, I am using the go-restful package (github.com/emicklei/go-restful)

Comment: what packages are you using? I don't know what is providing `WriteEntity`

Comment: whoops sorry I forgot to mention that, I am using github.com/emicklei/go-restful

Comment: Can you not do what you want with Filters alone?

Comment: This is a language feature called "functions" hth.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own function:

```
func writeEntity(r *restful.Response, value interface{}) error {
    // if value is an error
    if perr, ok := value.(PodsError); ok {
        r.WriteHeader(perr.ErrorCode)
        // reassign value so it gets wrapped: `{"error": value}`
        value = struct {
            Error PodsError `json:"error"`
        }{perr}
    }
    return r.WriteEntity(value)
}
```

Then just always call that instead of `response.WriteEntity`:

```
writeEntity(response, PodsError{http.StatusNotFound, "Calling Func", "Message"})
```